# Is there an option to move the most first(main) node on the top of the structure?

Tags: javascript, jstree

I want to modify the base structure of the tree.
I am currently on point where i try to change the position of the main root(the first one). I am trying to set it on the top of the whole structure(The main category to appear first and then the rest of the tree).
Here is what i mean: https://i.stack.imgur.com/YGeG3.jpg 
 I am not sure it is possible without touch of the source code.

I already search for this feature, but without success. Here is what i found and try so far. Not sure it is relevant, but as far as I understand there should be some plugin or something similar: https://www.jstree.com/api/#/?f=changed.jstree 
https://www.jstree.com/plugins/

This is the code so far:

```
$('#documentation_tree')
    .on('open_node.jstree', function () {
        $('.tooltips').tooltip();
    })
    .jstree({
        "core": {
            "themes": {
                "variant": "large"
            },
        },
        "types": {
            "default": {
                "icon": "fa fa-folder icon-state-warning icon-lg"
            },
            "file": {
                "icon": "fa fa-file icon-state-warning icon-lg"
            }
        },
        "plugins": ["types"]
    });
```

This code work fine, but it is not what i want to accomplish.

Comment: Hi! Did my answer helped you?

Comment: Hello, Jorge. Thank you for your answer, I really appreciate it. Your answer is very helpful. Actually it not solve my issue, but it is very relevant. I manage to accomplish this by adding the main category html element above the base structure... it is really simple solution, but i was thinking for something very complicated... my bad.

Comment: Oh well, I'm glad that it helped you, at least :-)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You have the `mode_node` API call, where you can change nodes parent to your likings.

API reference: https://www.jstree.com/api/#/?q=move_node&f=move_node(obj,%20par%20[,%20pos,%20callback,%20is_loaded])

Example:

```
var node = $('#documentation_tree').jstree("move_node", "NODE_ID", "#"); // # means root
```

NOTE: When you create nodes, they will return the ID of the node created OR you can pass an `id` parameter (along with `text`, `icon` and such) where you can say the node ID you want, and later use it to move the node.

Also, it seems that you want the rest of the nodes be the children of the node you moved, so you have to change it accordingly. Just move the node you want to be the parent and move the rest of the nodes to be the children of that node.